# ndk , cmake , and alot of other features aren't showing in my sdk manager and i dont know how to instal them to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, android-sdk-manager

ndk , cmake , and alot of other features aren't showing in my sdk manager and i dont know how to instal them to android studio
i tried several solutions including changing proxy settings , changing local time and date of my pc , trying diffrent pc , i updated android studio and even i tried vpn
still most features is not showing at all

[here is a picture of my sdk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk9BY.png)

i searched for weeks but still got no working solutions

***my android studio details :***

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 17, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: artsiomch.cmake (213.1.6), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40)

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to ask about a problem regarding to my sdkmanager in android studio .. if i want to setup ndk or cmake or any other similar plugin , its not appearing in sdkmanager for installation .. and i clarified the solutions i tried above .. now iam just waiting for an answer or someone with similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally after several trials , i simply removed everything and even resets my laptop .. then everything is working fine now after reinstalling java se and android studio